# Leaving battery in storage

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power

I am going to be away from my rMBP for 2 weeks, I powered it off and left it with around 56% of battery charge, anything I should do differently / didn't do? in order to keep the battery in a good condition without causing damage (losing capacity or getting it in too deep discharge state).

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly ok. You just shouldn't store batteries completely empty for a long time.

Comment: Any evidence to back this up?

Comment: Also, the most efficient long-term battery charge storage is about 2/3. This is the reason that most laptop/phone batteries are shipped to the customer at about that charge. (Source: research as well as personal experience with 4 iPhones, a rMBP, a MBA replacement battery and a dell laptop replacement battery.)